# Why code reverts back on reconfiguring the Remote Setting on Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I have a *Sitefinity project* that I deployed on **Windows Azure Cloud Service** using **Sitefinity Thunder**. But the problem is that I had changed some files manually using **VM instance** (Note: this user name is used in other configurations on other Cloud Services). Now after few days when I tried to connect to the **VM Instance** I got the following error:

```
Remote Desktop can’t find the computer [Azure Colud Service name]. This might mean that doesn’t belong to the 
specified network. Verify the computer name and domain that you are trying to connect to.
```

But, till then the website was running fine on Azure Cloud Service. Then I reconfigured the VM Instance & downloaded. But then the code on Cloud Service got reverted. Also the changes made on IIS for that instance were reverted back.

I searched a lot why this happened but got no valid reason. Please can anyone explain here, How can I avoid this situation. Also How can I deploy only changed files only on Azure Cloud Service. So that the code do not get revert back in any situation.

**EDIT:**

I mean **reconfigured VM Instance** here is the following step:
1) I Select the Cloud Service, the select the Configuration tab, then click on Remove button given at bottom. Plz. see image given below.
[image]

2) Then I fill the values & click the [Tick] icon.  Plz. see image given below.
[image]

3) Then, after completing the Reconfiguration, I select the Instances tab, then click the [Connect] to downnload the RDP file to connect to the VM Instance for Cloud Service. Plz. see image given below.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `Then I reconfigured the VM Instance & downloaded.`?

Comment: Plz. see the edit in my post.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is about losing the changes you made to the VM by manually logging in to the VM, then it is the expected behavior. Essentially Cloud Services VMs are `Stateless VMs` i.e. any changes you make to the VM after the VM has been brought up are not persisted. For many reasons your VM could go down and Microsoft replaces the VM. When Microsoft replaces the VM, it takes the code/binaries and settings from the package you last uploaded thus the changes you made will be lost.

For this reason, when deploying your code in a cloud service `it is not recommended that you make the changes manually`. If you have to make some changes, it is recommended that you do via `startup tasks`. These are executed when your VM is brought up and are part of the package. Obviously other alternative is to use Virtual Machines (IaaS) instead of Cloud Services. Virtual Machines are `Stateful VMs`.

Regarding your question about deploying only the changed files, unfortunately this is not possibly with cloud services. Your option would be to go with Virtual Machines or Websites.

Comment: hi thanks you for the answer. But as i researched more, it was written that Virtual Machines which are stateful VM'S as mentioned in your last post can also go down and data will be lost there as well? Is that is a case as well?

Comment: If Virtual Machines does not result in losing the data then we will go with that. PLease help in this case as we lost nearly all 5-7 last deployments with did manually via remote desktop on cloud service and code has been reverted back to first build which we did you sitefinity thunder.

Comment: Also now we are trying to update code changes via TFS to Cloud Service? is this something which can help us and satisfy our requirements where we want to only upload changed files because it is faster than uploading complete code via thunder deployment or build. What we are planning is : we update changed files to TFS from local environment and then connect visual studio online to our azure  cloud service and then update each revision of TFS to the cloud service. But we are stuck with some build errors when running code on VS online. Do you think we can deploy only changed files via TFS?

Comment: Too many comments :). Regarding 1st, can you share the link? Regarding 3rd, deploying code on Virtual Machines would similar to deploying the code on your local server. You can only push the files which are changed via FTP/Web Deploy/TFS.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. i think the second sentence you answered was for 2nd comment of mine. my third comment was misunderstood. Right now we have taken the approach of deploying code via TFS to the existing cloud service VM's as in that case we can atleast deploy the changed files rather than complete code. so my third comment was to ask you whether it is possible to deploy changed files code via TFS if we attach our visual studio online account with Cloud Service.I read this but ran into visual studio online build errors which i am correcting. will share link regarding 1st comment tomorow.